# I don't want to make 2 API calls for this

Tags: ruby, hash, facebook-graph-api, null, key-value

The following code does two things:

1. Checks to see if the item has the key "checkins"
2. Gets the checkins value if it has the key

I really don't like making two API calls for this. Its really slowed my code down but I'm forced to because if I make the API call for checkins and the key doesn't exist, then my code blows up. There must be a better way to do this.

```
if graph.get_object(self.place_id).has_key?("checkins") 
  checkins =  graph.get_object(self.place_id)["checkins"] - self.checkins
else 
  checkins = self.checkins
end
```

Comment: Not familiar with fb-graph-api, but couldn't you assign `graph.get_object...` to a variable, then do your magic?

Comment: if I do graph.get_object(self.place_id)["checkins"], then I'm returned with a nil

Comment: ... if checkins does not exist for that object (happens from time to time)

Comment: What is the class of `self.checkins`? Is there a possibility that the value of `[*(str1 unless str1.empty?), str2]` becomes `nil` even when there is a key to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
graph_checkins = graph.get_object(self.place_id)["checkins"]
checkins = if graph_checkins
             graph_checkins - self.checkins
           else
             self.checkins
           end
```

Comment: @JZ, I'm glad it helped.  Happy hacking!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I meant by my comment:

```
graph_object = graph.get_object(self.place_id) # assign return to variable
if graph_object.has_key?("checkins")
  # reference returned object, no need to request it again
  checkins = graph_object["checkins"] - self.checkins
else
  checkins = self.checkins
end
```

*I'd use `Wayne Conrad`'s example, simpler.